Nativescript RadCalendar scroll not working
I am currently using NativeScript version 8.7.2 for iOS. However, I am facing significant issues with RadCalendar, as it is generally very hard to access. Here are the specific problems I’m encountering:

When passing [minDate]="minDate" and [maxDate]="maxDate", the calendar scroll does not work, and the calendar screen becomes unresponsive, preventing access to any features. Additionally, it still does not navigate to the specific date I provided.

Without passing [minDate]="minDate" and [maxDate]="maxDate", the calendar scroll works fine.

This issue only iOS app not Android app.


<GridLayout>
  <RadCalendar [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="minDate" viewMode="Week" iosOverflowSafeArea="false"></RadCalendar>
</GridLayout>

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RadCalendarComponent, } from "nativescript-ui-calendar/angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-items',
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  minDate = new Date(2024, 9, 28, 10, 0, 0);
  maxDate = new Date(2024, 9, 28, 17, 0, 0);
  @ViewChild("myCalendar", { static: false }) myCalendar: RadCalendarComponent;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}

